# show ip route shows interface with /32 subnet mask

Tags: cisco, routing, router, packet-tracer

I am new to networking, and currently studying about how router learn different routes.
One of my lecture slides shows the following,

First of all, please have a look at this network,

[image]

I know that `link local` is created in the routing table when interface is configured, and `connected` is created when an interface is active.

Now, I tried the same scenario in Packet Tracer and here is what I got when i type `show ip route` command,

```
Router#show ip route 
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

C    192.168.10.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

My question is,

- If the interface is active why there is still two entries (`C` and `L`) in routing
  table (in the photo), and just single `C` entry in my network ?
- How come the diagram shows the ip address for link local
  with subnet mask of `32` because when I tried assigning ip address with `/32` subnet mask to this interfacce, I got bad mask error  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a /32 to an interface that connects to something else doesn't make any sense.  You can assign the /32 to a loopback interface:

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
```

If you want to assign the `192.168.10.1` address to the GigabitEthernet0/0 interface which uses `192.168.10.0/24`:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

This results in the network `192.168.10.0/24` entry in the routing table as a connected route (`C`).  I suppose it depends on the IOS version, but you can also get a local (not link local which is something else, entirely) route to the specific (`/32`) address assigned to an interface in your router.  My IOS does this.  The version you have doesn't show the `L` in the codes, whereas mine does as the first entry:

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override
```

`

Answer (score 3):

May can answer your question.

> If the interface is active why there is still two entries (C and L) in routing table (in the photo), and just single C entry in my network ?

[Prior to IOS release 15, local routing did not appear in routing tables](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2180210&seqNum=12)

> How come the diagram shows the ip address for link local with subnet mask of 32 because when I tried assigning ip address with /32 subnet mask to this interfacce, I got bad mask error ?

I think you can not assign directly /32 to cisco router interface.

Comment: You can certainly assign /32 addresses to loopback interfaces in a Cisco device. This is a very common practice.

Comment: thank you for your correction, never done it though in cisco loopback. but often does it on linux machine :).